# Application.Idle event triggering every time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a user control where i registered idle event under Load event of that control.

```
Control_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Application_Idle);
}
```

I know this will trigger when application finishes processing and reached idle state.But i really confused what is application here which goes idle, does that this usercontrol where load event register the idle event handler.When i put breakpoint every time it hits, what does this means?

For example i created a Form which contains this code

```
int counter = 0;
private void Form1_Idle(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;
    label1.Text = counter.ToString();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Idle +=new EventHandler(Form1_Idle);
}
```

then i create some buttens in that form which has certain operations to do.As per my understading label counter should not increase when i am doing operations through the buttons i created because its not in idle state, but now what happens is even some operation going on by clicking button lable counter is increasing, except if i press form  title bar and move the form around.

One more thing do i need to detach these event handler when close my window even if this is main application window. If so if i do in dispose method will that sufficient?

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
```

**UPDATE**
if i am pressing some text through keyboard say "LARSEN" ,between the press of alphabet "L" and "A" does idle event occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It triggers every time when it have processed all the messages and there are no messages left. As for disposing, per MSDN "Because this is a static event, you must detach your event handlers when your application is disposed, or memory leaks will result." - so I guess detaching it on form dispose (or probably on form close if its handler has something to do with the form) is enough.

**upd:** message loop [is started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902.aspx) in your Program.cs like this:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new frmMain());
    }
```

It processes all the messages like mouse move, key pressed and lots and lots more. You probably should read in length about it somewhere, possibly a book, but yes, there is an "idle" state after your first keypress is processed, long before you hit second key.

**upd2:** If you want to detect "real idle" you might want to start (and re-start) some sort of timer in this handler and when it expires maybe check CPU load or some such, depending on exact desired condition.

Comment: ok, so what is these messages you meant? where is this message queue. one more thing you didnt gave answer to my entire questions

Answer (score 3):

The Idle event is going to be called each time the application has some free time on its hands, not just once. If you want it to be called once, detach the event handler after you're done, like so:

```
Application.Idle -= Application_Idle;
```

That's the way you should detach from the event before shutting the application down, as well.